# JRootPane.getName() returns Null?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to debug a pretty nasty error (my panel is not being displayed even though it is added to the JFrame) and I noticed that the JRootPane inside of my JFrame has a name that is set to null:
(This is a piece of my JFrame constructor)

```
this.add(uiRenderer/*This is a JPanel*/); //adding the panel to the jframe
System.out.println(this.getRootPane().getName()); //getting the name of the root pane
```

Is this normal? Or could this be causing the panel to not be displayed at all? What could be causing this? On a side note, the JRootpane itself is not null, just the name String inside it that getName() returns. I can get the components inside of the rootpane just fine and that displays the panel I am trying to add to the JFrame but it is still not showing up.
Thanks!

Ok so it is potentially a java version bug. Apperently this null name happens in an old version of java. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4836615
Thank you to whoever let me know about this.

Comment: Despite what that bug report says, there is, as far as I know, no guarantee that any child of a JRootPane will be assigned a name.  Those names could change in the next minor Java release.  I would not rely on them.  If you want to debug a Swing component tree, you can try Ctrl-Shift-F1, which will dump the entire tree of the currently focused window.

Answer (score 1):

[`JRootPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html) inherits `getName()` from it's parent, [`Component`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html), and `JRootPane` does not override the method. If you do not explicitly set the name to a non-null value, `getName()` will return `null`. A typical implementation is seen [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/awt/Component.java#l998). It calls the package-private method `constructComponentName()`, which returns `null` unconditionally.

```
String constructComponentName() {
    return null;
}
```